# Maximum number of folders in a library

Tags: apex, content, libraries

Is there a limit for the number of folders a library can have? If so, what is the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce documentation has not mentioned this limit. There is a limit for the number of folders in a library, Maximum 500 folders could go in a library.

Attached the images showing error messages while trying to create a folder in a library that has 500 folders, Dev log while trying to add a folder from a VF page.

[image: Error while trying to add a folder using a VF page]

[image: error while creating folder in a library]

Comment: Please add some evidence to back up your claim.

Comment: We've encountered the same 500 folder per library limit... this seems to remain an undocumented limit

Answer (score 1):

As far as documentation is concerned, there isn't. However, there are limitations to the number of libraries as well as the number of files:

- Content: maximum number of libraries - 2,000
- Content: maximum number of content documents - 30,000,000

Further information on limits can be found in the [help article about Salesforce Files and Salesforce CRM Content Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_file_size_limits.htm&type=5).