# Is there a limit for number of content folders?

Tags: visualforce, soql, content, contentversion, contentdocument

I am getting this error when I try to create a content folder using a visual force page(by inserting a record in contentfolder. As per this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179633/maximum-number-of-folders-in-a-library), there should not be any limit for the number of folders to be created. This is my dev org. First is there a limit for a number of content folders? I have read so many documents about the limitations for this. but nowhere this number of folder limitation was mentioned. Could this org only have this limitation?

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LIMIT_EXCEEDED,
>   Can't create Content Folder XXXXXXX. You've reached the 500 Content
>   Folders limit

Comment: If you have already created 500 folders and you are getting this exception then there must be this limit even if it's not mentioned in documentation. You can contact Salesforce support for more information this might be varying with editions.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce documentation has not mentioned this limit. There is a limit for the number of folders in a library, Maximum 500 folders could go in a library.